How to convert non-readable PDF into readable PDF with OcrMyPdf: troubles with tesseract and configparser
I'm trying to convert a scanned PDF into a readable one.
The original PDF contains text, tables, images/logos. The desired output file should be exactly the same of the original file.
I found different strategies on the web to do it in Python:
https://basilchackomathew.medium.com/best-ocr-tools-in-python-4f16a9b6b116
https://medium.com/@dr.booma19/extracting-text-from-pdf-files-using-ocr-a-step-by-step-guide-with-python-code-becf221529ef
https://ploomber.io/blog/pdf-ocr/
I'm trying to use the OcrMyPdf because it seems to be the most direct way for the conversion. Once installed, as well as its dependency tesseract,  I tried to run this code:
import ocrmypdf, tesseract

if __name__ == '__main__':
    file_path = r'C:\Users\...\Desktop\Test.pdf'
    save_path = r'C:\Users\...\Desktop\Test_ocr.pdf'

    ocrmypdf.ocr(file_path, save_path, deskew=True)

Surprisingly, I got this error:
 File "C:\Users\...\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\tesseract\__init__.py", line 34
    print 'Creating user config file: {}'.format(_config_file_usr)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?

that I corrected adding the () to the print call.
Running again the code, I got the exception:
 File "C:\Users\...\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\tesseract\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import ConfigParser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'

that I subsequently installed. But running the code again, I still got the same execption:
 File "C:\Users\...\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\tesseract\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import ConfigParser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'

Even importing the ConfigParser module into my code, I got the same exception.
I'm trying to run the code into Windows 11 using Python 3.11.5. I installed the following packages with Pip:
ConfigParser 7.0.0
OcrMyPdf 16.4.1
Tesseract 0.1.3
This is the Tesseract init file:
#!/usr/bin/python
"""
tesseract
=========

A package for measuring the concentration of halos from Nbody simulations 
non-parametrically using Voronoi tessellation.

Subpackages
-----------
voro 
  Routines for running and manipulating data returned by the Voronoi
  tesselation routine vorovol.
nfw 
  Routines relating to fitting and determining properties of NFW profiles.
io 
  Routines for data input and output.
util
  Misc. utility routines
tests
  Routines for running and plotting different tests for the provided test halos.

"""

# Basic dependencies
import ConfigParser
import os
import shutil

# Initialize config file
_config_file_def = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"default_config.ini")
_config_file_usr = os.path.expanduser("~/.tessrc")
if not os.path.isfile(_config_file_usr):
    print('Creating user config file: {}'.format(_config_file_usr))
    shutil.copyfile(_config_file_def,_config_file_usr)

# Read config file
config_parser = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config_parser.optionxform = str
config_parser.read(_config_file_def)
config_parser.read(_config_file_usr) # Overrides defaults with user options

# General options
config = {}
if config_parser.has_option('general','outputdir'):
    config['outputdir'] = os.path.expanduser(config_parser.get('general','outputdir').strip())
else:
    config['outputdir'] = os.getcwd()

# Subpackages
import voro
import nfw
import io
import util
import tests


__all__ = ['voro','nfw','io','util','tests']

How can I run that simple code for PDF conversion?

You first of all submit an issue report on the package's home page!

Otherwise: the expectation that OCR will deliver you more than just the text, is an illusion. I only know non-free products (like AWS Textract) coming close to this.

The direct conversion is what I expect, and what OcrMyPdf declares to do. Look at this link
